# Given two vertices and one point of hyperbola, construct its foci

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, conic-sections, geometric-construction

**Points $P$,$Q$ and $S$ are given. Construct the foci of hyperbola **$H$** such that $P$ and $Q$ are its vertices and $S$ is one of its points.**

How to solve this problem using only euclidean geometry methods?

Comment: I think you should correct "parabola" to "hyperbola" in your text.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca now I understand why it got downvoted. I didn't even realise what I wrote until now, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct through the midpoint $C$ of $PQ$ its perpendicular bisector, intersecting lines $SP$ and $SQ$ at $P'$ and $Q'$ respectively.
Semi-conjugate axis $BC$ is the mean proportional between $CP'$ and $CQ'$.

Comment: I'm really interested in knowing how you came up with this idea to solve the problem, I would have never thought of it on my own. I knew that the length of the semi-conjugate axis is exactly what I needed but I didn't know how to find it

Comment: @kaykay It's Problem 95 on page 166 of this book: https://archive.org/details/constructivegeom00eagluoft/page/166/mode/2up